# OAuth/ SAML authentication with ASP .Net Web API framework

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, single-page-application, okta

I am working with a project where frontend is Angular 4. It consumes Asp.Net WEB API services. I have implemented token based authentication for accessing restricted api calls along with refresh token implementation.

Now i want to implement additional authentication mechanism like Native AD, ADFS and other third party services like OKTA using SAML 2 authentication.

I want to understand flow how it will work with web api along with Angular SPA.

Answer (score 0):

These are the flows you could use. https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/implementing-authentication/ and Okta already have SDKs that can help you https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/angular/nodejs/generic. <- uses    Implicit flow.

Comment: thanks but i am looking for generalized approch by which i can easily connect to okta or any saml supported systems.